# WillPopScope disable the swipe left to go back in IOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I use WillPopScope in my flutter app and it disable the "Swipe left to go back" that is really usefull in IOS. How to keep the WillPopScope but re-add the iOS gesture ?

WillPopScope not working on ios for swipe left to go back.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior, too. When I wrap my navigator with `WillPopScope` and place a breakpoint in `onWillPop`, the breakpoint isn't reached. The same breakpoint is reached on the Android emulator system back button, but no the iOS "swipe left to go back". I'm not sure why this issue isn't getting more discussion as it seems pretty critical.

Answer (score -2):

Render the WillPopScope base on the Device Type

```
  return     Platform.isAndroid ? new WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
               },
              child:.......
```